# Linux DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) custom resolution and timings

Tags: linux, screen-resolution, timing, framebuffer

I'm trying to make some kind of video generator in order to test monitors. For this I'm trying to avoid any X and window manager so I'm stuck with a non GUI Linux.

I was able to write directly into the framebuffer device under Linux but I wasn't able to change the resolution at all. Fbset didn't have any effect.

With the help of [a tutorial](https://github.com/dvdhrm/docs/tree/master/drm-howto), I was able to change the resolution with DRM but only modes that my screen is telling that it is supporting.

Is there any way to disable the EDID readout at all or inject custom timings?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But by DRM i meant the Linux Direct Rendering Manager. Its a interface to set modes directly on your Graphics Card. Its some kind of low level API.

Comment: As an aside, I think you might want to remove the DRM tag as it refers to Digital Rights Management here usually, so may be steering people the wrong way. Interesting question - is there a reason you need to avoid windows managers to test your monitors?

Comment: Good point, thanks. The reasons are that i want to be sure that no driver is somehow manipulating the output image and i want it to be slim and fast as well. Plus since I'm working on this, i learnd a lot of how Linux works inside which i would not with an GUI application. And since its possible with X to ignore the EDID and inject custom timings it must be possible without as well. I already tryed to find it in the source code of X and its components but unfortunately its way to much and complicated.

Comment: If `fbset` doesn't work for you, then you're going to have problems getting your code to work either (it will be using the same kernel interface as `fbset`).  Which framebuffer driver are you using?  Is there a good reason not to use a KMS driver (they also expose framebuffer interface, with suitable kernel config).  Given that we can't yet tell whether your problem is with your system or your code, this question may be better suited for [unix.se].

Comment: I would be happy to use the AMDGPU driver but with it i was only able to write into the fb0 device and draw on the screen. When i tryed to change the resolution with fbset it resulted in smaller letters from tty but the output signal from the graphics card stayed the same. Also fbset displaed timings as 0 0 0 ... 0. With the Vesa driver i got the right timings from fbset but wasnt able to change the resolution at all.

Can you tell me more about the sutable kernel config with a KMS driver?

Answer (score 0):

you can stuff whatever values you want into the drmModeModeInfo structure before initializing drm. so any custom video mode is possible.